# Approving information prior to storing in database?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am developing a web-based iPhone app and possibly a PC friendly website version as well. The goal here to to allow users to submit a form where specific input values would be stored into a table in the database.

Mind you this information is being gathered for public display and will be posted onto a calendar or list.

However, to prevent from any trolling or spamming, I'd like to make it where submissions have to be approved prior to being submitted into the table.

I have no problem with creating the table, connecting to the database, storing input values into the corresponding table columns. The only issue is how would I go about setting up an approval system? Can I add information to a table via email? Is there a way to approve admissions in cPanel?

This is something that I would like make as smooth as possible, I am expecting a lot of submissions daily with quite a bit of information.

Comment: If user enter the data into a `form`, check ,if all `$_POST['column']` have your desire value and after approve, insert them into database.

Comment: who will do the approving and how? most systems would post first then delete spam afterwards unless you have people watching 24\7

Comment: @Dagon Since this would be a service being provided to a large audience in a huge region this would have to be flawless and in that case I would want human approval. And my question is about how, or if it is even possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have two approaches for this.

**Approach 1**

- Have two copies of the table (which you want to save information
  into). The first one should be named tableName_Input. The second one
  should be tableName_Final.
- Any Data in '_input' is considered raw and needs approval. Once approved the data will be moved into '_final'. The LIVE list/calendar always read from '_final' data.

**Approach 2**

- Have a column named 'isApproved' with a flag 0/1. If 1 it is approved, else it is not. Only show data that is Approved.

Now, how do you get the data approved ?

- You have a hard fast rule like spam filter that tells certain post is valid and approved by default
- After every post, you send the user an email or some notification (unique to the user - post) that when answered back, shall mark it as approved.

*Optional*: You can place a column called as 'approval comments' to fill in something at the time of approval.

**Flow chart**

*Tables*

- 'FirstSubmitContent' - Table to store user submitted information
  prior to approval.
- 'FinalSubmitContent' - Table that stores the final information

*Code Pages*

- Content Page --> Contains the form the user fills the content
- ContentActionPage --> Calls the controller --> calls the Model
- Controller --> calls the model based on page action
- Model --> Interacts with the Database table

[image: Flow Chart for the various steps in the process]

I do not have any tools at my disposable now to write more detailed Code or Flowchart. I hope this puts in the right direction.

Comment: Good answer, not exactly what I was looking for. I see an issue of not only spamming but incorrect information input. I would like to get new information approved manually by human rather than email validation on the user end. However, if an email with details could be sent to an admin and then an admin approve via link then that would be perfect.

Comment: You can always do that. 2 steps approach. Validated by User and then by Admin. This gives a polished process where user is sure of his/her edits (and can change it before submitting it for approval). On the other hand, Admin or Approver (you name it) gets a notification after the user approves it. Rest as you said in your comment.

Comment: @Sanjeev Okay, so to answer my question, how would I go about, coding wise, submitting a form full of table information, getting approval from user and admin vis email, and then properly store it into the table?

Answer (score 1):

Validate the form on submission and save info in a temporary table in your DB with a randomly assigned activation code (you could use `sha1`). Then send an email to user with activation code and a link to verify it, ie. `domain.com/activate.php?code=abcde12345`.

The activation page can be very simple with just a `$_GET['code']`. Then check if you find a match in the DB for that code and finally prepare your query with all the info you gathered before to store it permanently.

Then you can make a cron job to delete all records from that table every 24-48 hours so users will have to activate within that time range.

Comment: can you imagine id S.O di that for every post\comment\answer ?

Comment: @Dagon: I don't understand exactly, what do you mean?

Comment: @elclanrs Almost same answer and you beat me by a minute :)

Comment: Yes, both great answers and I learned something new today. Thank you!